# JQuery Function Not Firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this function inside my header, and it was working perfectly, until today. I have made zero changes to the document, except that now the function does not fire at all.

I have trued putting an alert outside the function & that works, but an alert inside does not fire whatsoever.

Any thoughts on where this has gone wrong???

**Jquery includes:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Script:**

```
 // THIS ONE WORKS
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

$(function() {
  // THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

  var cost = 1500;
  var industry = 0.07;

  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 50000,
    max: 250000,
    step: 5000,
    value: [ 95000 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#slider-amount").val(ui.value);
      $("#calc-result").val("$" + (ui.value * industry - cost).toFixed(0) );

      var result = "$" + (ui.value * industry - cost).toFixed(0);
      $("#calc-result2").text(result);

      var salary = ui.value;
      $("#salary").text(salary);
    }
  });

  $("#slider-amount").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
  $("#calc-result").val("$" + ($("#slider").slider("value") * industry - cost).toFixed(0));

  var result = "$" + ($("#slider").slider("value") * industry - cost ).toFixed(0);
  $("#calc-result2").text(result);

  var salary = $("#slider").slider("value");
  $("#salary").text(salary);
});
```

I have also tested just this **(does not work)**:

```
$(function() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
});
```

But this DOES work:

```
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
```

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error - the website was loading on an SSL cert, so was https:// , therefore it was blokcing the loading of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I removed the http: protocol and it started working! See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```